# Call existing stored procedure from Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using the latest `EF Core 1.1.1` with `.NET Core`. Now I want to implement some generic code inside `OnModelCreating` method in my `ApplicationDbContext` class to call any existing SP from db. Please note, I have both my model classes as well as database tables. So neither do I want any migration nor want to specify SP params for a particular SP inside `OnModelCreating`. It should be a generic implementation that can be used for any SP. My sole purpose is to call any existing SP from databse.

Entity:

```
public class Product
{
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public decimal Price { get; set; }

}
```

ApplicationDbContext Class:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
  public ApplicationDbContext ()
  {
   Database.Connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLExpress;Initial 
   Catalog=CallingExistingSPFromEFCore;Integrated Security=True";
  }

  public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
   modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().MapToStoredProcedures
  (
       //What should be the implementation here ?
  )

      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK guys so I found that in case migration is not needed, We can skip the `OnModelCreating` method and just go ahead with `OnConfiguring` method.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
      {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=servername;Database=dbname;Trusted_Connection=True;");

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe EF Core 1.1 supports Stored Procedures as of yet.  Check out the comparison of EF 6.X vs EF Core 1.1 here:

[Entity Framework Feature Comparision](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/features)

Comment: You can call procedures using FromSql(). But my concern is regarding the implementation of OnModelCreating(), since in all the examples they are using code-first/databse-first migration.